# Constructor/initialization in Cordova Plugin Development

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

am new to cordova and am currently developing a plugin, I want my users to pass value(e.g regID, and regPass) to the native side i want this to be done immediately the initialize fuction is called.
this is the function I want to use to handle the request from js

```
public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
}
```

My js file look like this

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    console.log('initialize function is called: '); 
    this.init();
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');        
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
   function init(){
         var regId="userid";
         var regPass= "password";
         var initArray = new Array(regId,regPass);
         var init = MyPlugin.init("init",initArray);                 
         init.done(function(response){
            console.log("initialization on going...");
          });
          init.fail(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
         });
     }
};
app.initialize();
```

but I don't know how to receive the value (regId and Pass) from the initialize method on the native android side, I will appreciate any help in right direction be it tutorial or blog post

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it

Comment: Cool. Could you please help me with some code?

Comment: check out the code repository at https://github.com/techquest/cordova-payment-plugin